# Error al instalar WAMP con apache

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Estoy intentando instalar wamp en un windows server 2012 x64.

La versión de wamp, es la última que tienen publicada en su página. 3.1.7

Al momento de terminar la instalación me parece el siguiente mensaje:

> The procedure entry point isalpha could not be located in the dynamic
>   link library c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.3.7\bin\pcre.dll

No logro encontrar la solución a esto.

IIS no está instalado.

Nota:
Estoy viendo que esa dll está siendo utilizado por otro proceso.
Qué alternativas tengo de compartir esa dll?

Comment: descarga una versión mas antigua.

Comment: Wamp en intranet es aceptable. Para soluciones en internet, considera evaluar otras tecnologías

Comment: @lkabod también probé. Aparentemente es un tema de dll compartida. Existe otro proceso que utiliza la misma, en otra ruta. Es posible compartir o referenciar la dll?

Comment: @fredyfx es únicamente intranet

Comment: para Windows 64: asegúrese de haber instalado el paquete redistribuible de Visual C ++ 2010 SP1 x64 
: VC10 SP1 vcredist_x64.exe >> [ www.microsoft.com ] 
Apache no se ejecutará sin este componente 


(VC ++ 2008 también debe instalarse como el menú WampServer utiliza las bibliotecas de: debe instalarse de forma predeterminada en la mayoría de las versiones de Windows, solo marque Agregar o quitar programas para ver si está en la lista)

Comment: Trata de hacer una instalación limpia, quita el programa desde el menú de agregar o quitar programas , y elimina la carpeta que se creo de wamp.

Comment: @lkbod están instalados los Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 y 2012.

Comment: @lkbod también hice la instalación limpia, eliminando todo, pero aún sigo con el mismo mensaje de error.